# How do ES6 imports/exports work when creating objects/variables in a module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given I have a `Config` class in a file called `Config.js` and I have the following module in a file called `myConfig.js`:

```
import Config from './Config.js';

const myConfig = new Config();

export myConfig;
```

If I have multiple files that `import { myConfig } from 'myConfig.js'`, does it instantiate new Configs on each import statement?

Comment: you can just `console.log()` before the `export` and see how many times your script works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 modules are singleton.
Each time you import the module you will get the same instance.
However, you could have tested it quite easily by logging something in the Config constructor.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First: remove the .js extension when loading modules.

Second: your config class should be exported using `export default class Config {}` if you intend to load it with `import Config from 'modulename'`

The value exported is a singleton and will not change or reinstanciate but still why have config as a class? It should be a const object like

```
export const Config = {stuff:1}
```